# Почему на css файлах сайтов так много строк:(

Tags: css

Всем привет я совсем новичок на разработке сайта есть опыт работы в нескольких простых сайта на django. Так вот вопрос в чем, когда заходишь на css файлы сайта там так много строк > 20 k. В моих проектах они максимум не доходит до 1к :( Frond разрабы все эти многотысячные строки сами пишут или они использует какие то удобные инструменты? И эти css файлы для одной страницы или в целом для сайта?

Comment: *это - норма (с)*

Comment: ну есть разные плагины, которые подключают, normalize, к примеру, если какие-то другие библиотеки используются и они требуют своего файла стилей, то тоже туда же)

Comment: Греты Тунберг на них нет...

Answer (score 4):

Для стилей используют [препроцессоры](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/CSS_preprocessor), например:

- [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/)
- [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)
- [Stylus](https://stylus-lang.com/)
- [PostCSS](https://postcss.org/)

У каждого из них свой синтаксис и свои преимущества, я использую `SASS`, мне удобен его синтаксис и я ничего не использовал кроме него, поэтому я буду субъективен.

---

Расскажу немного про `SASS`, или же его вторую версию `SCSS`.
Различия между `SASS` и `SCSS` это синтаксис, например в `SCSS` используется закрытие метода.

### SCSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 0;

    .block {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #000;
    }
}
```

### SASS:

```
body
    margin: 0
    padding: 0
    line-height: 0

    .block
        width: 50px
        height: 50px
        background-color: #000
```

После сборки мы получим готовый `CSS` код:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
body .block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

---

Конечно это только синтаксис, дальше - лучше. Переменные, примеси, модульность, циклы и многое другое.

Расскажу по порядку на примере `SASS`. (по-моему личному мнению он лучше чем стиль `SCSS`)

### Переменные:

```
$backgroundColor: #ccc

body
    background-color: $backgroundColor
```

## После сборки:

```
body
    background-color: #ccc
```

---

### Примеси:

```
@mixin reset-list
    margin: 0
    padding: 0
    list-style: none

 nav ul
    @include reset-list
```

## После сборки:

```
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

---

### Модульность:

Файл `header.sass`

```
.header
  width: 100%
  height: 60px
  position: sticky
  top: 0
```

Файл `footer.sass`

```
.footer
    width: 100%
    height: 300px
    background-color: #c0c0c0
```

Файл `main.sass`

```
body
    margin: 0
    padding: 0

    @import './header.sass'
    @import './footer.sass'
```

Таким образом можно разделить проект на небольшие части, чтобы удобнее было работать, и с ними работать, а в конце получать готовый `CSS` код который будет включать в себя такие модули.

---

### Циклы:

```
@for $i from 1 through 12
  .col-#{$i}
    width: 100 / 12 * $i
```

### После сборки:

```
.col-1 { width: 8.3333333333; }
.col-2 { width: 16.6666666667; }
.col-3 { width: 25; }
.col-4 { width: 33.3333333333; }
.col-5 { width: 41.6666666667; }
.col-6 { width: 50; }
.col-7 { width: 58.3333333333; }
.col-8 { width: 66.6666666667; }
.col-9 { width: 75; }
.col-10 { width: 83.3333333333; }
.col-11 { width: 91.6666666667; }
.col-12 { width: 100; }
```

Это лишь малая часть для того, чтобы заинтересовать вас использовать препроцессоры, но дальше изучайте документацию по [ссылке](https://sass-scss.ru/documentation/).

В качестве сборки используются такие сборщики как: [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/), [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). Готовый [boilerplate](https://github.com/cferdinandi/gulp-boilerplate) (шаблон) можно скачать с любого `github` репозитория. Вам так же понадобится [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/).

В итоге проект на 20 тысяч строк, может быть разбит на маленькие части и каждый файл может не занимать и больше 100 строк, нужно лишь правильно организовать проект.